# Nuxt3 useFetch throws : TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "immediate" in "$oZ6l5I0Zbt"

Tags: vuejs3, polygon, nuxtjs3

I am trying to query NFTs associated with a specific account on the
polygon chain.

```
  { data } =  useFetch(() => 'https://polygon-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/Kfwf-JWJK/getNFTs?owner=AccountId')
```

However, this results in the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "immediate" in "$oZ6l5I0Zbt"

The URL that I pass to the method is correct. I can lookup the information on the account in my browser.

Comment: I ran into the same error. The solution was to use the third parameter and set it manually.
`useFetch(url, {}, { immediate: true })`